# Transformation of dates in pandas dataframe to the specified format working only for a single format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

I wrote a function that converts all the dates of the specified date column to the specified format. Any missing or invalid date is replaced with a value specified by the user.

The issue is, all the dates are being converted to the same default format '%Y/%m/%d', regardless of the format specified.

**Code:**

```
# Date Formatting
  
from dateutil.parser import parse
import pandas as pd

def date_fun(dfd, date_inputs):
    try:
   
        col_name = date_inputs["DateColumn"]
        replace_date = date_inputs["ReplaceValue"]

        date_col = dfd[col_name]

        formatted_dates = pd.to_datetime(date_col, errors='coerce')
        
      #   dayfirst=True   
      #   formatted_dates = pd.to_datetime(date_col, errors='coerce', dayfirst=True)
      #   formatted_dates = pd.to_datetime(date_col, format='%m/%d/%Y', errors='coerce')
      #   formatted_dates = pd.to_datetime(date_col, format='%Y/%m/%d', errors='coerce')
      #   formatted_dates = pd.to_datetime(date_col, format='%d/%m/%Y', errors='coerce')

                       
        if replace_date is not None:
            formatted_dates = formatted_dates.fillna(replace_date)
        dfd[col_name] = formatted_dates

        
        result_dict = dfd.to_dict(orient='records')
        for record in result_dict:
            for key, value in record.items():
                if isinstance(value, float):
                    record[key] = str(value)
        return result_dict
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"An error occurred while performing the operation: {e}")
```

**Column Data**

```
25.09.2019

9/16/2015

10.12.2017

2008,13,02

23-01-1992, 7:45
```

**My Output**

```
2019-09-25T00:00:00

2015-09-16T00:00:00

2017-10-12T00:00:00

2008-02-01T00:00:00

1992-01-23T07:45:00
```

Why is the conversion of dates to the specified format not happening?

**NOTE:**  I kept the different formats that I tried in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `pd.to_datetime()` returns a [`pd.Timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html#pandas.Timestamp) object. You then use `str(timestamp)`, which defaults to an [ISO format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string. You can use you [`<timestamp>.strftime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.strftime.html) instead, and get a different output format.

As far as I can tell from your example, Pandas correctly converted your input strings.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states that format specifies the way the time string to be parsed is expected, not the output date format.
here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html